# I have published OAuth consent screen on google cloud. Its been week still get no response from them

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I have applied for google cloud OAuth consent screen verification. Its been more than week still got no response from google team. As mentioned there `Expect the first email from our Trust and Safety team within 3–5 days.`

[image]

What am I suppose to do in this case??

Comment: StackOverflow cannot help you with Google customer support issues. In my experience, you will need to wait for them to respond.

Comment: I agree with @JohnHanley Hanley. It's either you wait for the response from the Trust and Safety team's response or you can reach to support again to make a follow up

Comment: My request was not getting processed as I got one mail which I missed to check. We have to reply to that mail to start verification.